# set UITableView.Style to .insetGrouped based on device/traits

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I wanted to use the new iOS 13 table view style `.insetGrouped` only on iPad or based on size variation traits.

Sadly it's not possible to change the UITableView style after the init: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/style

Changing it in the storyboard is also no option as there is no way to change it based on size classes.

I'm currently using this code, but nothing changed:

```
class DetailViewController: UITableViewController {

    […]

    override init(style: UITableView.Style) {

        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            super.init(style: .insetGrouped)
        } else {
            super.init(style: style)
        }
    }


    // Xcode forced me to include this as well?
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @alexkaessner. Did you figure out how to accomplish this?

Comment: @SAHM Sadly no, for now I just used the old style setup in interface builder.

Comment: If you have a storyboard, then `init(coder:)` is the initializer that is called.

Comment: @Sulthan I tried to set `self.tableView = UITableView(frame: self.tableView.frame, style: .insetGrouped)` in `init(coder:)`, but it crashes on startup

Comment: @alexkaessner You just cannot do such a thing. Either you set the style in your storyboard/xib, or you set it using `init(style:)` when creating the table view controller. These methods cannot be combined. You cannot change the table style after creation, which means you cannot change table style of a controller loaded from storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Create UIViewController with 
`

```
var tableView: UITableView!
init(...) {
    if ??? {
        self. tableView = UITableView(style:...)
    } else {
        self. tableView = UITableView(style:anotherStyle)
    }
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
}
```

`

Comment: I tried to set `self.tableView = UITableView(frame: self.tableView.frame, style: .insetGrouped)` in `init(coder:)`, but it crashes on startup

Comment: use CGRect.zero as a frame and add it ti a view hierarchy + constrains in next line. You have recursive reference
self.tableView = ..(frame: self.tableView.frame.....

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that currently works is terrible and awful from a maintenance perspective, but at least you get the effect you want for your users: just make a duplicate of your storyboard and adjust the `style` property in the duplicate storyboard. When done, load the correct storyboard depending on the device or whatever criteria you want to use:

```
var resource = "StoryboardName"

if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
    resource += "Large"
}

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: resource, bundle: nil)
```

Comment: Thats indeed not ideal! Maybe I‘ll wait until I can drop the older OS or switch from storyboard to code only.